# Orika mapping spring's org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, orika

I'm sorry to bother you with this question but I end up finding a head stomper, and I am wondering if I'm dealing with this the wrong way.

I want to map a class containing a collection of `org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority` so that I don't need to send it eagerly loaded by the ORM, into the spring security classes. But its "role" attribute is associated with the getter "getAuthority", and that is when Orika means trouble. Can I force Orika to use the values returned by a getter, to put it into a setter of the destination class?

If you care enough, here's a little context ot my problem. 
I'm using Spring security for an app. I have a service which returns a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` so that spring can check if the user is authenticated and it has permissions. The implementation of UserDetail we have is a local one named `User`. Since this class implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`, it has the method `public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();` which returns the permissions for this user.

Everithing was well, except for the fact that we had this `User` in the database, handled with hibernate. The first choices where to leave an open session in view. We don't want that. The second choice was to make the fetching of the ORM, EARGER. We didn't want that either. So, we decided to use a DTO, implementing UserDetail, and map it with orika. That's when all hell broke loose. `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority` is an interface. The concrete class we are using is `org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority`. And this is an obscure and deadly class to map, because it has an attribute name "role", but its getter is "getAuthority"

```
public String getAuthority() {
    return role;
}
```

It appears that the Spring team and the Orika team where not very close friends. Otherwise they would've name the property, according to the java standard, and orika would've mapped it straight forward. I am, also, reluctant to define a custom mapper for this particular case, and that's what's been bothering me. Is there any known way of forcing Orika to use the value returned by the getter method other than replacing all its 'magic' with a custom mapper for a particular class?

Comment: Why don't you want to make getAuthorities() eager?  (not challenging, but want to understand constraint)

Comment: The idea was to avoid letting our buisness objects beyond the service.

Comment: But isn't User going beyond the service?

Comment: Also, our roles are tied to a "center", so, a user can be "owner" for a center, and "user" for another. When set to eager, hibernate retrieved several objects, because there were several rows, but we acctually had 1, associated with many roles. Can that be a mapping issue?

Comment: The fact that User is going beyond the service is something we want to avoid. Actually, it was going "facaded" as a UserDetail

Comment: It sounds like it.  I've implemented Spring Security ACL's ontop of hibernate before withou any problems.  I'll post an answer with how we have it setup

Comment: It would be helpfull. Though I would still like to know if mapping the GrantedAuthority of spring is some known problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end, it pays to be stubborn as I am :)

I fixed the issue in question without having to appeal to any trick. The problem that was interfering with my mapping was the generic on the collection returned by the getter. You'll see, it seems that orika can't handle the following mapping... at least, I didn't know.

```
public List<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.role;
}
```

I changed it into

```
public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.role;
}
```

and worked just fine!

Thanks a lot for the time and attention!

Comment: At runtime those are exactly the same.

Comment: At runtime all lists are exactly the same

Comment: Yes, but Orika uses Type objects to gather the generic information.

Answer (score 1):

We have roles (which extend GrantedAuthority) setup like this in our user object:

```
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return roles;
}
```

Note it's lazily loaded, but switching to eager fetch shouldn't cause problems:

```
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return roles;
}
```

I'm not too familiar with Orika, but in glancing at its docs, it seems you could just extend GrantedAuthority quite trivially with a Hibernate-enabled entity that would be straightforward for Orika.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll sure try that. It's a little different to the model I've inherit, but a refactor might be the proper approach.

Comment: @coya added a possible approach to deal with Orika